# AppleScript instruction to set webcam in FaceTime

Tags: applescript, facetime

I need to automate a FaceTime call using AppleScript, but one of my requirements is to pick a specific webcam. I am trying to use this code:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell process "FaceTime"
    tell menu bar 1
        tell menu bar item "Video"
             click menu item "Webcam 520X"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

But I got this error message:

System Events got an error: Can’t get menu item "Webcam 520X" of menu bar item "Video" of menu bar 1 of process "FaceTime".

Any suggestion about how to do it in the right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is always a `menu` reference between the `menu item` and its `menu bar item`

```
activate application "FaceTime"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "FaceTime"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "Video"
                tell menu 1
                    click menu item "Webcam 520X"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

or

```
activate application "FaceTime"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "FaceTime"
        click menu item "Webcam 520X" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Video" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```